# How to load a jquery plugin when a dialog opens and then execute the plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my app I have the ability to open a dialog an upload an image.

When he dialog opens there is a line to load the js plugin:

```
<script src="xxxxxx.js" type="text/javascript">
```

The plugin is: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Then later in the dialog I init the uploader with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   $('#fileupload').fileupload({ .....
});
</script>
```

The problem is sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't w/o firing an error. Is there a better way to handle this? Ideas?

The reason i load the uploading plugin in the dialog is only admins can load the dialog so requiring all users to download the jquery plugin seems wasteful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the $.getScript() function?  Details at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/  Might be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Libraries tend to help with these type of processes by taking into account items like cross browser compatible methods for doing things like this.  Essentially they have probably done the research on what your trying to do and built a method to make sure it works reliably.  You'd have to pull the jquery source and look through the function details for specifics.